# Angular reactive forms dropdown hack in transparency for <option> tag

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am working on an angular 8 project.

I am looking to stylize my reactive forms dropdown to be partially transparent.

Here's what I got thus far.

obviously this is the easy part.

what I want is for the choices to be on the same slightly transparent background instead of opaque white  :

```css
body{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(45, 173, 108) 0%, rgba(227, 253, 200, 0.9));
}

  .custom-select{
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.16);
  }
  // this either does nothing or removes it's own alpha value, inconsistently
  // both behaviors aren't desired.
  option{
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.16) !important;
  }
```

```html
  <form [formGroup]="statusForm">
    <div>
      <div class="text-label">Topic :</div>
      <select class="custom-select" (change)="onStatusChosen($event)" formControlName="status">
        <option value="Delivered">Delivered</option>
        <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
        <option value="UndeliveredTechnicalissue">Undelivered/Technical issue</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
```

adding style to the option tag even with the `!important` flag, doesn't do it.

I also tried `-webkit-appearance: none !important;` with no better results.

I'm using the latest chrome ideally this solution would work under edge as well. no other browsers need to be supported.

Comment: Short answer - you can't. Not with the native HTML select: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: you need to use a custom select library to do that due to system limitations, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element

Comment: why not? also I beleive a reactive forms dropdown can be done without a select and option tags.

Answer (score -1):

set the background option, like below :

don't use #rrggbbaa hex color notation, It's not very well supported yet.

for transparency use rgba() instead of hex 8 digit.

```css
body{
  background: lightblue;
}

.custom-select1, .custom-select2{
  background-color: #80808029;
}

.custom-select1 option {
  background-color: rgba(51,51,255,0.2) !important;
}

.custom-select2 option {
  background-color: rgba(51,51,255) !important;
}
```

```html
  <form [formGroup]="statusForm">
    <div>
      <div class="text-label">Topic : Transparent</div>
      <select class="custom-select1" (change)="onStatusChosen($event)" formControlName="status">
        <option value="Delivered">Delivered</option>
        <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
        <option value="UndeliveredTechnicalissue">Undelivered/Technical issue</option>
      </select>

      <div class="text-label">Topic : Not Transparent</div>
      <select class="custom-select2" (change)="onStatusChosen($event)" formControlName="status">
        <option value="Delivered">Delivered</option>
        <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
        <option value="UndeliveredTechnicalissue">Undelivered/Technical issue</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: i just give you example , you free to change the color what you like. and i also point there #rrggbbaa will not work because i already try it, it work if you use rgba()

Comment: see my edit, your rgba won't work because the default option background color is white.

Comment: i see u need to transparency your option against your background, you can't do that, like @suresh mention option is not supporting transparency against its background

Comment: well then say that straight up instead of hiding that fact. either way, like I told him there's probably a way to hack this in.